# How to make file starting with underscore ( _ ) appear in output?

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

In my JS library I've noticed that none of the files starting with an underscore are appearing in my output from JSDoc3. These are marked using @module and I've tried adding @public and also building with the -p switch but I can't seem to get them appearing. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've discovered that if you run JSDoc using a configuration file (http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html#configuration-file-command-line) you can update the excludePattern which by default includes files starting with the underscore pattern.